# Is the Python Johansen cointegration test trustworthy?

Tags: time-series, cointegration

I'm trying to learn how to do Johansen's cointegration test.  I am using the Python's "statsmodels.tsa.vector_ar.vecm.coint_johansen".

I have run 10 tests, each with 5 series.  All series are different from each other.  Most have 2 significant Eigenvalue/Trace values, but some have 3.  However, I noticed something weird.  What's strange is that the first 2 are significant, the next 2 are not, and the last one is significant.

Should I switch to maybe doing analysis in R instead?
[image]
[image]

This question also seems to point out some discrepencies:
[Why are the critical values in coint_johansen in statsmodels in Python so different from the ones in ca.jo in urca in R?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/374202/why-are-the-critical-values-in-coint-johansen-in-statsmodels-in-python-so-differ#comment876785_374202)